# Migration pathways

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As we have now graduated I have looked at all the migrations we have made since May 2011, and I think the 3 obvious migration routes for us are:

- Meta
- Music Fans
- Sound Design

We have also migrated a fair few to Video Production (mostly on soundtracks and scores) so could we have that as a fourth. Those would cover 85% of all the migrations we have ever made.

**Edit as of April 2016**

Over the last 90 days we have had 1 migration to Sound Design, and 19 to Music Fans. That shows our most important target...

Comment: Can we set up migration pathways to sites still in beta?

Comment: Ahh - that's a very good point Dom. I have a feeling we can't. Looks like we may have to stick with mod requests :-/

Comment: We have migrated posts to English and to Electronics but they were very rare.

Comment: "Meta" being Meta.StackExchange?  Or does Meta.Music take up a slot?

Comment: Law might also be of use

Comment: Meta being Meta Music, Matthew - yes, it takes up one slot. Law may be of use, but as per Dom's comment, it is still beta.

Comment: Yeah, the only site that we REALLY need a migration path to is Music Fans, and that's still in beta.

Answer (score 2):

Since we get a lot of software recommendation questions,  I suggest getting a migration pathway to software recs.

Comment: think it's still in beta...

Comment: @DrMayhem it's in the same position as us. http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/congratulations-software-recommendations-is-graduating

Comment: In that case we may get it - good spot!

Comment: I'm not sure what the status that Dom referred to in November was, but I see that at least as of today Software Recs no longer says "Beta" on the site, and this would certainly be an often-used migration pathway. Hence this ping/reminder on the topic (of which I was reminded due to the recent closure of a software search question).