# Why was this question migrated so quickly?

Tags: discussion

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26205/application-to-identify-which-chord-could-it-be-by-given-notes

I saw this on Music Practice questions, and went to add an answer, and poof it was gone.  Now if I want to answer it I have to register for that other board.  Why should I do that?  I'm not in the habit of recommending software.

By the way the question asked for 'an application'.  The one answer is for a web site.  I wanted to add an Android App.  Neither of these are 'software' in the usual programming sense.

[Software / online purchase of guitar / piano loops](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/39068/software-online-purchase-of-guitar-piano-loops)

https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/39074/a-better-alternative-to-garage-band

are 2 newer questions that did not get migrated.  What's different about them?

Comment: See: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/2299/are-questions-about-software-tool-recommendations-allowed

Comment: Also it's super easy to join another SE so that should not prevent you from answering a question on another SE.

Comment: So was I wrong to recommend the `smartchord` app for this question: http://music.stackexchange.com/a/38708/23218?

Comment: IMO, it's not really a good fit here and would be better on a site like software recs.

Comment: Then someone needs to assign it a useful tag or 2, something like 'music-composition' (6 entires).  Or be merciful and just put it one hold as off topic.

Comment: We have a composition tag already. I'm not really sure what you're getting at with the tags as this is more about scope than anything else

Comment: When that question was migrated it was left tagless, reducing the chance that someone knowledgeable would notice it.  I see that you answered one 'music-composition' question on that board.  What led you to that question?  Ultimately my concern is - what maximizes the chance that this poster will get useful answers?

Comment: Tags are independent across sites, we can't help it if the destination site has no matching tags -- it has to be edited after the fact.

Comment: Shouldn't the person who migrated it take responsibility for finding a few good tags?  IF the real goal of the migration is help them get good answers.  But I doubt if that's the real reason for migration.

Comment: I agree that this question is a better fit here than SW recs. It does seem to be the current feeling that such questions are off-topic but I'd like to see that changed - see my answer to the question Dom linked to in the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't answer off-topic questions.  And if you don't want to register for a site that accepts such questions/answers, you don't have to — but that really has nothing to do with us.

Quick migrations are exactly what we want.  The OP doesn't need to sit around while we debate and dither, delete/lock posts, etc.  They should be directed to the place where they can get their question addressed as soon as possible.

As for why the other two were not migrated — a moderator was not involved with their closure.  A non-moderator cannot suggest a migration to a site that is not one of our set migration paths.  Right now the only option is Meta, but soon an option for Music Fans will be added.  If you feel that Software Recs should be added instead of Sound Design, please add an answer here and explain: [Migration pathways](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2284/28)

Comment: The reason I objected is that I figured there are more musicians on this board who know about relevant apps than there are software gurus on that board who know about music.  So far that question has gotten 2 poor quality answers.  I've seen the same thing happen when questions got moved from SO to Code Review - they died of neglect.

Comment: @hpaulj Rocken Cowboy *is* from our site and if you want to answer the question there you can. We don't recommend software period because the site is very focused on specific topics of music practice and theory rather than suggesting software to someone. The question is off-topic here and on-topic there.

Comment: @hpaulj Also SO and Code Review have completely different scopes.

Comment: It looks like Rocken Cowboy followed this migration link over.  Good for him.  I chose not to.  I suspect that if the OP had just asked about 'resources' it would have stayed.  Books and static web pages are apparently ok, dynamic pages and apps are not.